# Reading the file related information inside a folder using Java

Tags: java, directory, file-handling

Here is the scenario I have.

I have a job running that will place the files in this folder say **x**:
The "X" folder has deafault windows folder properties such as Name, Date Modified, Type and Size ,
I need to get the above columns and copy them in different variables for every file. Currently I am unable to do it.

This is my code:

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {

```
    String path = "X";
    File file = new File(path);
    String[] dirList = file.list();
    for(int i=0;i< dirList.length; i++){
        String fileName = dirList[i];
        System.out.println("File Name :"+fileName);
            String filepath = path+fileName;
            File file1 = new File(filepath);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy  HH:mm:ss aaa");
            System.out.println("Date Modified : "
                    + dateFormat.format(file1.lastModified()));
            String fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.length()-3, fileName.length());
            System.out.println("FileType :"+fileType);
            System.out.println("FileSize :"+file1.length()/1024);
        }
}
```

If there is another way to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide more information about what is going wrong. Exception or output expected and actual and etc.

Comment: The code is working fine , there is no error but its not populating the values properly in the variables eg : except name, the other three parameters that are date modified,size and type are not getting properly added to variables. I could have posted a screenshot but my reputation isn't allowing me to do so.